# Annotation in Kotlin doesn't work

Tags: java, android, annotations, kotlin

I'm trying to convert my Android app from Java to Kotlin.
For app shortcut I use [shortbread](https://github.com/MatthiasRobbers/shortbread) library which is extremely easy to implement, but it doesn't work in Kotlin. Am I doing something wrong ?

Java:

```
@Shortcut(id = "Camera", icon = R.drawable.iconshortcut,longLabel = "Instant Scan", shortLabel = "Scan")

public class CameraActivity extends AppCompatActivity { ...
```

Kotlin :

```
@Shortcut(id = "Camera", icon = R.drawable.iconshortcut, longLabel = "Instant Scan", shortLabel = "Scan")

class CameraActivity : AppCompatActivity() { ...
```

Shortbread is working whenever the annotation is in Java, but not in Kotlin

```
Shortbread.create(this)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to use the `kotlin-kapt` plugin to be able to parse annotations in Kotlin files:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

dependencies {
  ...
  implementation 'com.github.matthiasrobbers:shortbread:1.0.2'
  kapt 'com.github.matthiasrobbers:shortbread-compiler:1.0.2'
}
```

If that doesn't work it'd probably make sense to open an issue in the GitHub repo of the project.